# The document class ''cas-dc'' cannot print Table

Tags: tables, els-cas

```
\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{\textcolor{green}{Evaluation of actual and predicted load }}
\label{tableFE}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  *{9}{S[table-format=1.2]} % 9, not 10
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{forecast models} \\
\cmidrule{3-10}
{Hours} &
{Target (\si{\kilo\watt})} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{FCRBM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{AFC-ANN} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bi-level} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{MI-ANN} \\
\cmidrule{3-4}\cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{7-8}\cmidrule{9-10}
 &                                                        % <---- this was missing
 & {P.load (\si{\kilo\watt})} & {MAPE (\%)}
 & {P.load (\si{\kilo\watt})} & {MAPE (\%)}
 & {P.load (\si{\kilo\watt})} & {MAPE (\%)}
 & {P.load (\si{\kilo\watt})} & {MAPE (\%)} \\
\midrule
22.00& 672.6923 & 676.0057 & 0.4926 & 681.0057 &1.2822 & 630.1417 & 6.3456 & 675.9192 & 0.4797\\ [1ex]


\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Did you try with tabular* instead of tabular? Please also make your code a complete small example document by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Please also add if you get an error message and if so, which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `tabular*`, not `tabular`.

I also propose a few improvements, mainly moving the units on a new line and specifying carefully the number of digits.

```latex
\documentclass{cas-dc}
\usepackage{natbib,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Evaluation of actual and predicted load}
\label{tableFE}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{forecast models} \\
\cmidrule{3-10}
{Hours} &
{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Target \\ (\si{\kilo\watt}) \end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{FCRBM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{AFC-ANN} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bi-level} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{MI-ANN} \\
\cmidrule{3-4}\cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{7-8}\cmidrule{9-10}
 &
 & {P.load} & {MAPE}
 & {P.load} & {MAPE}
 & {P.load} & {MAPE}
 & {P.load} & {MAPE} \\
 &
 & {(\si{\kilo\watt})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\kilo\watt})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\kilo\watt})} & {(\%)}
 & {(\si{\kilo\watt})} & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
22.00& 672.6923 & 676.0057 & 0.4926 & 681.0057 &1.2822 & 630.1417 & 6.3456 & 675.9192 & 0.4797\\ [1ex]


\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]